# Adding a LIMIT higher than the average number of rows returned?

Tags: apex, soql

Let's say they do a search for Contacts with a filter `Name = 'John Smith'`.

Out of a couple million Contact records and assuming there are 600 records that match this criteria, would it make a difference if I add `LIMIT 1000` to the end of the query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more specific. Right now the body of the post contains one fairly specific question (adding a `LIMIT` higher than the number of rows returned), but your post title is extremely broad and may get your question closed.

Comment: Best advice I have on questions like this is to run a few developer console queries & compare the results.

Comment: @battery.cord I've been messing with different queries, but the response time jumps around drastically. It makes me think that there's some caching going on.

Comment: If you really want to dig into why some queries run faster than other, check out the [Query Plan tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1). It'll help provide more information about the behavior of different queries.

Comment: Yes, the Salesforce database stops early when you hit the LIMIT, so you will get better performance if you limit the query.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes but say only 600 records match and the limit is 1000. I would assume the query keeps looking for more after it's found all 600 because it hasn't hit the limit yet. I'm wondering if it's useful to consider these things in an apex class where the same query gets run a bunch with slightly different parameters and the average response is less than 1000 rows.

Comment: @battery.cord Thank you so much for showing me the Query Plan Tool. That is immensely helpful.

Comment: @battery.cord Recommending use of the `Query Plan` tool is a good answer here.

Comment: I would not think the limit would cause the query to keep looking. When it finds all 600 it knows already there is no more so the limit is ignored. At least that’s what I would expect